# how to add a frame to camera captured image and save it

Tags: android

I want to add a transparent image over the camera captured image and save it to the external storage.in this code i can take the image from camera and save it to external storage.is anyone know that how to add a image overlay to captured image and save it,please tell me how to modify this code.

This is my Main3Activity.java file

```
package rahula.shannirmala.com.blueandgoldperade2016;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.File;


public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView imageView2;
    static final int CAM_REQUEST = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
        imageView2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        Intent camera_intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File file = getFile();
        camera_intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
        startActivityForResult(camera_intent,CAM_REQUEST);

    }

    private File getFile()
    {
        File folder = new File("sdcard/Blue_&_Gold_Perade");
        if (!folder.exists())
        {
            folder.mkdir();
        }

        File image_file = new File(folder,"selfie_cam.jpg");
        return image_file;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        String path = "sdcard/Blue_&_Gold_Perade/selfie_cam.jpg";
        imageView2.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(path));
    }


}
```

This is my activity_main3.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context="rahula.shannirmala.com.blueandgoldperade2016.Main3Activity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The overlay you want to add is a Jpeg, Png? what is the size of the overlay(pixels)?

Comment: i want to add a png file.no idea about the pixel size, i want to add the overlay image over the captured image.if the camera is 13 megapixel,overlay image should get the pixel size of that taken image and must overlay in it.sorry about my english.

Comment: Please try my answer below, I used a different path to save the pictures, you don't have too.

Comment: please look at the below answer

Comment: Please try the edited version, don't forget to add the permission.If you are building to 23 API you will be prompted for the permission during application run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add write external storage permission to the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

The activity:

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity {
            private static final String LOG_TAG = "error";
            ImageView imageView;
            static final int CAM_REQUEST = 1;
            Date curentTime;

            // Storage Permissions
            private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
            private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            };

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

                verifyStoragePermissions(this);

                imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
                Intent camera_intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File file = getFile();
                camera_intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
                startActivityForResult(camera_intent,CAM_REQUEST);

            }

            private File getFile()
            {
                curentTime = new Date();
                String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                File folder = new File(root + "/Blue_&_Gold_Perade");
                if (!folder.mkdirs()) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Directory not created");
                }

                File image_file = new File(folder,"selfie_cam"+curentTime+".jpg");                    
                return image_file;
            }


                @Override
                protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent     data) {
                    setAndSaveImageWithOverlay(getBitmapOfSnappedImage());
                    }

                public Bitmap getBitmapOfSnappedImage(){


                    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                    String path = root + "/Blue_&_Gold_Perade"+     "/selfie_cam"+curentTime+".jpg";

                        File image = new File(path);
                        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                        Bitmap bitmap =     BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath(),bmOptions);
                        return bitmap;
                    }

                public void setAndSaveImageWithOverlay(Bitmap snappedImage){
                    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(snappedImage.getWidth(),     snappedImage.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

                    //the overlay png file from drawable folder
                    Bitmap overlay = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),     R.drawable.overlay);
                    overlay =     Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(overlay,snappedImage.getWidth(),snappedImage.getHeight    (),false);

                    //create canvas with a clean bitmap
                    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(b);
                    //draw the snappedImage on the canvas
                    canvas.drawBitmap(snappedImage, 0, 0, new Paint());
                    //draw the overlay on the canvas
                    canvas.drawBitmap(overlay, 0, 0, new Paint());

                    imageView.setImageBitmap(b);

                    SaveImage(b);
                    }


                private void SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

                    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                    File myDir = new File(root + "/Blue_&_Gold_Perade");
                    myDir.mkdirs();
                    String fname = "selfie_cam"+curentTime+".jpg";
                    File file = new File (myDir, fname);
                    if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();
                    try {
                        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                        out.flush();
                        out.close();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                /**
                 * Checks if the app has permission to write to device storage
                 *
                 * If the app does not has permission then the user will be prompted to grant permissions
                 *
                 * @param activity
                 */
                public static void verifyStoragePermissions(Activity activity) {
                    // Check if we have write permission
                    int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

                    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        // We don't have permission so prompt the user
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                                activity,
                                PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                                REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                        );
                    }
                }

        }
```

Comment: i checked this code and it is show the overlayed image on image view, but the image saved in the gallery is no overlay.its only the original image.how to save the captured image with the overlay? please help me

Comment: I run the code on my machine and it works fine, you got the bitmap with  the overlay ready " imageView2.setImageBitmap(b);" and then you save it in your chosen location. // get the path and save the image again with the overlay. you can save it in a different location of your choice.

Comment: yes finally its working brother.thank you very much.you are the best.thank you so much for your help.thank you again

Comment: Glad that I could help! :)

Comment: one more question brother, the first image with overlayed is saved in the Blue & Gold Perade folder and when i captured another image that image is replace to previous image.only the last image is only in the folder.how to set that to save  all the overlayed images taken

Comment: it was saved always in the same location, I have edited the post so now it will be saved with a date generated on the go, so it will be saved with a new path every time.

Comment: yes, its working. one last question please... my overlay image is a potrait image and when i take a photo in potrait it overlayed nicely without any problems.but the landscape images show creeped overlay image.can we use if function and check if the image orientation is potrait and then use potrait overlay image and else the image rotation is landscape use landscape overlay image? this is the only question i have now,any help please

Comment: I will give you a diraction on this one: as you can see we can check the width and height of the image (snappedImage), 'snappedImage.getWidth(), snappedImage.getHeight()'. The values will be different when the image was taken in portrait mode or landscape. With that you could decide the rest. Take it from here :)

Comment: i have no idea how to that, if the values for potrait and landscape are change then how to identify the difference and add landscape overlay image to that? I am new to the Android programming.I dont know much about the programming tricks.can you update the above answer one so that i can try to understand how to that.

Comment: finally i understand how to do this and i do that brother.i used this method "if (snappedImage.getWidth() > snappedImage.getHeight())........" and its working.thank you very much for your help bro.

Comment: That's great man, the best feeling is to achieve it by yourself, good luck :)

Comment: ooops.got another problem.all before codes are worked perfectly on my android mobile.but now i installed the application to another device.when i open the camera and take the picture it says "unfortunately application has stopped working". i tried the your last code without two overlay images but it is same.but all the before and after coded apk file is working perfectly on my mobile.my mobile is htc one m7 which has 4mp camera.now i tried the apk on 8mp camera.can you tell me what is the problem in here?

Comment: Please post it as a separate question, if it's not resolved, talk to me.

Comment: I posted it as question.question name is FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Comment: this is the question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35116486/fatal-exception-main-error?noredirect=1#comment57953437_35116486

Comment: Roman i found the solution for the application has stopped working problem.the problem for that is getting an null value for curent time.i fix it.99% of the problems are now solved in my application.one last problem is getting an wrong orientation on camera captured image view in some devices. i saw a answer for that question.it says "Most phone cameras are landscape, meaning if you take the photo in portrait, the resulting photos will be rotated 90 degrees. In this case, the camera software should populate the EXIF data with the orientation that the photo should be viewed in."

Comment: and this is the his solution "ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(photoPath);
int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

switch(orientation) {
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
        rotateImage(bitmap, 90);
        break;
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
        rotateImage(bitmap, 180);
        break;
    // etc.
}"    can you tell me how to add this solution for my source code?